# How I can mutate a struct's field from a method?

Tags: rust, mutable

I want to do this:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn up(&self) {
        self.y += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
    p.up();
}
```

But this code throws a compiler error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to field `self.y` of immutable binding
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
7 |     fn up(&self) {
  |           ----- use `&mut self` here to make mutable
8 |         self.y += 1;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow field of immutable binding
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You need to use `&mut self` instead of `&self` and make the `p` variable mutable:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn up(&mut self) {
        // ^^^ Here
        self.y += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
    //  ^^^ And here
    p.up();
}
```

In Rust, mutability is inherited: the owner of the data decides if the value is mutable or not. References, however, do not imply ownership and hence they can be immutable or mutable themselves. You should read the [official book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) which explains all of these basic concepts.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I just want say that even if you read and worked through the book, having never seen these concepts before, it might not make much sense until you run into an actual situation where it is relevant. As it was for me, so these answers are still really helpful ;)

Comment: @Aeolun - Very well said.  I went through The Book, and thought I understood the concept, but discovered I really didn't until I started working on an actual Rust project.

Comment: The book is not perfect.

Answer (score 20):

By using `Cell<T>` you can emulate field-level mutability:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: Cell<i32>,
}

impl Point {
    fn up(&self) {
        self.y.set(self.y.get() + 1);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x: 0, y: Cell::new(0) };
    p.up();
    println!("y: {:?}", p.y);
}
```

This will print `y: Cell { value: 7 }` and we've successfully updated `y`.

Additionally, if you are using `nightly` channel, you can declare `#![feature(cell_update)]` on top of your `.rs` file and use the following syntax inside your `up()` method:

```
impl Point {
    fn up(&self) {
        self.y.update(|x| x + 1);
    }
}
```

Note: This feature above is a nightly-only experimental API.

From [*The Rust Programming Language* at Rust 1.7](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/mutability.html).

Comment: Does the same apply for Box, Rc, Arc?

Comment: Yes, it does. And you can combine them, for example: `Rc<Cell<i32>>` ... `y: Rc::new(Cell::new(0)),`.